# async / await + yield / next order of execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

Sorry in advance for the long post! Below is a code example I'm reviewing and the log outputs:

```
const a = () => new Promise( resolve => {
  setTimeout( () => resolve('result of a()'), 1000);
}); 

const b = () => new Promise( resolve => {
  setTimeout( () => resolve('result of b()'), 500);
});

const c = () => new Promise( resolve => {
  setTimeout( () => resolve('result of c()'), 1100);
});

// async generator function
const MyAsyncGenerator = async function*() {
  yield await a();
  yield await b();
  yield await c();
};

// generator object
const gen = MyAsyncGenerator();

// get 'gen' values
(async () => {
  console.log(await gen.next())
  console.log(await gen.next())
  console.log(await gen.next())
  console.log(await gen.next())
})();

(async () => {
  await Promise.all([a(), b(), c()]).then(res => console.log(res))
})()
```

```
{ value: 'result of a()', done: false }
[ 'result of a()', 'result of b()', 'result of c()' ]
{ value: 'result of b()', done: false }
{ value: 'result of c()', done: false }
{ value: undefined, done: true }
```

I'm trying to figure out why `Promise.all([...]).then()` is logged second. Here's my best explanation but would really appreciate any additional insights:

1. Since there are two anonymous async IIFEs (Immediately Invoked Function Expressions), while the first `gen.next()` evaluates the result of `a()`, the `.then()` method on the new Promise returned by `Promise.all()` is pushed to the microtask queue
2. After the first `await gen.next()` is logged to the console, the call stack is empty, so the event loop pushes `.then()` to the call stack next

I'm ultimately unsure whether it has to do with the task vs. microtask queue or when `Promise.all()` is fulfilled relative to the generator iterations. My understanding is that `setTimeout()` goes to the task queue, but if we include `Promise.all()` in the same code block under the generator iterations, the logs are in order:

```
(async () => {
  console.log(await gen.next())
  console.log(await gen.next())
  console.log(await gen.next())
  console.log(await gen.next())
  Promise.all([a(), b(), c()]).then(res => console.log(res))
})();
```

```
{ value: 'result of a()', done: false }
{ value: 'result of b()', done: false }
{ value: 'result of c()', done: false }
{ value: undefined, done: true }
[ 'result of a()', 'result of b()', 'result of c()' ]
```

Comment: `Promise.all([a(), b(), c()])` will resolve after `1100` ms. The second `gen.next()` will be called after `1000` ms and resolve after an additional `500` ms - `1500` ms > `1100` ms.

Comment: `I'm trying to figure out why Promise.all([...]).then() is logged second` > async IIFE's here don't wait for anything. The call to `Promise.all()` does not wait for any await resolution, because its not using any of the awaited results.

Comment: `await` specifically means *"leave the current function, and see what else is there to do in the current program"*. All things happen when their timer hits, nothing in your program chains that `Promise.all()` to "after the generator is done".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your program with timestamps of what happens when.

The `@ x ms` is meant to be absolute time (idealized, of course), `T+x ms` is meant to be relative time. Things with `@ 0 ms` happen "at the same time", when the program starts.

```
const wait = (value, ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms));

const a = () => wait('result of a', 1000);
const b = () => wait('result of b', 600);
const c = () => wait('result of c', 1100);

const MyAsyncGenerator = async function*() {
  yield await a();                             // T+1000 ms   
  yield await b();                             // T+ 600 ms
  yield await c();                             // T+1100 ms
};

const gen = MyAsyncGenerator();                // @    0 ms

(async () => {
  console.log(await gen.next());               // @ 1000 ms
  console.log(await gen.next());               // @ 1600 ms
  console.log(await gen.next());               // @ 2700 ms
  console.log(await gen.next());               // @ 2700 ms
})();                                          // @    0 ms

(async () => {
  await Promise.all([a(), b(), c()])           // @    0 ms
    .then(res => console.log(res));            // @ 1100 ms
})();                                          // @    0 ms
```

From this it's obvious that the `Promise.all()` will be done between the generator's first and second output.

Note that your second function is an example of useless use of `async`/`await`. Nothing follows the `await`, so waiting makes no sense. It would be better written as

```
(() => {
  Promise.all([a(), b(), c()])
    .then(res => console.log(res));
})();
```

and since the IIFE does not make a whole lot of sense here, either, it would be even better as

```
Promise.all([a(), b(), c()])
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

---

Bonus

```
const gen2 = MyAsyncGenerator();

(async () => {
  console.log(await gen2.next());
  console.log(await gen2.next());
  console.log(await gen2.next());
  console.log(await gen2.next());
})().then(() => {
  Promise.all([a(), b(), c()])
    .then(res => console.log(res));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I didn't appreciate the fact that `await` only blocks the thread within its scope, but when thinking about it, it definitely makes sense, hence the async concept. So I would either have to chain `Promise.all()` the way you did or expect them to run simultaneously.

Comment: @S.D. also provided helpful context that `await` doesn't impact Promise.all() because it doesn't depend on the awaited result to execute. Thanks again!

Comment: @buddyco `await` does not block at all, and there is only one thread. Maybe think of it like this: `await` puts a bookmark in the current function, so to speak, and gives control back to the event loop. Wenn the anticipated event (promise resolution) occurs, control returns back to the function at the last bookmark position.

Comment: Super helpful way to think about it, thanks a lot!